# wordpress hooks при создании нового поста

Tags: wordpress, post, hook

Здравствуйте.
При использование хука save_post, он срабатывает и на изменение статуса поста, например с черновика на корзину, и т.п. Как исключить эти срабатывания?

```
function premoderationTA() {
  if  (wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && get_post($post_id)->post_status != 'pending')
    return;
  mail('test@test.com', 'wp_subject', get_post($post_id)->post_status);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'premoderationTA');
```

Comment: А вы неправильно переписали условие в if отсюда: https://wp-kama.ru/hook/save_post. Потому и срабатывает.

Comment: Это условие изначально нам не подходит, требуется отправка письма **только при сохранении** сейчас функция срабатывает и при смени статуса, например с pending на draft

Comment: В каком статусе у вас пост, когда при сохранении надо отправить письмо? Опубликован уже?

Comment: Нет, нужен pending, срабатывание требуется только когда юзер кинул пост на пендинг(никуда кроме него и не может кинуть). Но при смене статуса письма, например с пендинга на драфт, срабатывает хук